# How to access the argument of a sass mixin?

Tags: css, sass

I'm making a sass mixin like this:

```
@mixin hello($arg1, $arg2, $arg3) {
// content here
}
```

I need to access the number of arguments in this mixin dynamically (in this example, I should get 3) to be used inside the mixin itself.

Second, I need to access the values of these arguments according to the argument index. I imagine something like this:

```
argsList[0] = 'arg1'
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

there is no native function allowing you to do that in sass. If you need to pass X parameters to your mixin, you should use an "arglist" in your mixin declaration. See the following :

```
@mixin hello($args...) {}
```

This allows you to pass as many $args as you want.

The only other way is to declare as many mixin as you've got $args, one for each case.